# Access to Service from Remote and Local JBoss 7

Tags: linux, networking, jboss

I have two different servers (i.e. a tomcat on port 8082 and a jboss on port 9080) on a Suse Linux machine. The first one has been installed some time ago and the second one I just installed recently. Now I have problem to access the second one from another machine.

If I look at the netstat output there is a difference:

```
user@server:/etc> netstat -l -n|grep 8082
tcp 0 0 :::8082 :::* LISTEN
ser@server:/etc> netstat -l -n|grep 9080
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

it seems that the 9080 server is restricted to 127.0.0.1 whereas the first one has :::.

UPDATE:

I changed the standalone.xml configuration file from

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
</interface>
```

to

```
<interface name="public">
    <any-address />
</interface>
```

but there is still a difference when I call netstat, and I can still not connect to the server from remote:

```
netstat -l -n |grep 9080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Where does this difference originate and what is the semantic of this difference?

Answer (score 2):

JBoss 4.2 and later only listens on localhost by default, you need to add -b 0.0.0.0 to your run.sh launcher (init scripts etc) to make it listen on all available interfaces.

Comment: is it possible that jboss 7 has a different handling there?

Comment: Possibly, I'd expect both solutions to work. Yours is slightly better as it will persist across restarts etc with no risk of the person starting jboss forgetting the bind.

Comment: This is wrong for JBoss AS 7, the -b ... syntax only works up to JBoss AS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we configure our JBoss AS 7 like this:

```
<interface name="management">
    <inet-address value="..."/>
</interface>
<interface name="public">
   <inet-address value="..."/>
</interface>
```

Where '...' is the actual IP or hostname of the machine the JBoss AS 7 is installed on. Works without problems up to now - what exactly is it that is not working in your case?

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work for you try to check iptables. (`sudo iptables -F` temporarily remove all rules so you can check if iptables blocks you communication).

To check if JBoss is listening: `sudo netstat -tlnp`
To list iptables rules: `sudo iptables -L -n`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your socket is bound to an IPv6, try to use any-ipv4-address element instead

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
        </interface>

        <!-- IPv4 -->
        <interface name="any">
            <any-ipv4-address/>
        </interface>
</interfaces>
```

You can also try to use `any` interface in the socket-binding-group

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any">
```